# Print dictionary pretty way in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

Is there any way to print a dictionary from a class in a pretty way?

I have a dictionary and when I print de class I want to return it with its keys and its values, like this:

key1: value1

key2: value2

...

I can't find a way to return it this way.

Here is where I want to put the code

```
def __str__(self):
   for key in self.__dicc:
      d = str(self.__dicc.get(key))
return d
```

Comment: [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint)?

Comment: yes, but I don't want the brackets @deceze

Comment: `'\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in self.__dicc.items())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through a dictionary key-value pairs using `items` method

```py
def __str__(self):
    d = ""
    for k, v in self.__dicc.items():
        d += f"{k}: {v}\n"
    return d
```